# how to manually position multiple divs within another div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this layout [image: 1]] The black thin line shows the border of the outer div. Inside, there are two divs (red and blue). I would like to position them next to each other with a little space in between. Additionally, the top/bottom of the red div and the top/bottom of the blue div should be equal. The left and right should also be equal. This should be equal no matter the size of the browser.

I've tried playing around with the margins but I can't do it so that its exactly equal. Here's is the link for the full [code](https://codepen.io/smrak/pen/dVKwvN) of my attempt.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
#about {
   background-color: #D1C9BE;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: black;
   position: relative;
}

#aboutImage {
   border-style: dotted;
   border-color: white;
   background-color: red;

   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   margin-top: 200px;
}

#aboutInfo {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: blue;

  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: right;

  margin-left: 20px;
```

}

Also is there a way to automatically size a div based on how much text is in it? I've seen solutions for two divs of equal size just positioned side by side but how would I do so with two divs, different sizes?

Comment: You should look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flex-box.  Plus don't mix flex box and traditional positioning styles.
You can accomplish what you need with `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-evenly;` and `align-items: center;`

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

/* FULLPAGE */
.section {
    height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

/* ABOUT */
#about {
 background-color: #D1C9BE;
}

#aboutImage {
 border-color: white;
 background-color: red;
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
}

#aboutInfo {
 border-color: white;
 background-color: blue;
 font-size: 35px;
}

#aboutInfo p {
 font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <section id="about" class="section">
   <!-- Picture -->
   <div id="aboutImage"></div>
   
   <!-- Description -->
   <div id = "aboutInfo">
    Lorem Ipsum.
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br> Suspendisse malesuada lacus commodo enim varius, <br> non gravida ipsum faucibus. Vivamus pretium pulvinar <br> elementum. In vehicula ut elit vitae dapibus. Cras ipsum <br> neque,  finibus id mattis vehicula, rhoncus in mauris. In <br> hendrerit vitae velit vel consequat. Duis eleifend dui vel <br> tempor maximus. Aliquam rutrum id dolor vel ullamcorper. <br> Nunc cursus sapien a ex porta dictum.
        </p>
    
   </div> 
   
  </section>
    
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: The correct value for `justify-content` is `space-around`.

Comment: @tobiv not really. space-around leaves a half-size space at the ends.  See the spec:. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Comment: I stand corrected, space-evenly fits better in this case I guess!

Comment: thank you! is there a way to move the two divs closer to each other? for example, larger white spaces for the left and right but still equal values?

Comment: There are probably several ways to do that. one way might be to put a wrapper around all of it with a little bit left and right padding

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex.
For the parent container, type it

```
.container { 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction:row; 
    align-items: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for that. It will help you horizontally (`justify-content`) and vertically (`align-items`) center your elements with equal space around them (`justify-content: space-evenly`). In this case your child elements don't need any extra styling.

```
#about {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;

  padding: 20px;

  background-color: #D1C9BE;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

#aboutImage {
   border-style: dotted;
   border-color: white;
   background-color: red;

   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
}

#aboutInfo {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: blue;

  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

As for your last question re automatically sized divs, this is actually the default if you omit the `height` property. The div will then be just as tall as your number of lines of text (assuming you keep the `width` set).